# Why does the following code display the cookie rather than reading it?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I tried to create a login page using javascript as seen below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
  function myfunction(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost/Gardening-System/select_user.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {uname: username, psw: password },

      success: function (obj, textstatus) {
        if (!('error' in obj)) {
          var user = obj.result; // Define user variable here
          document.cookie = "username=" + username; // Set the cookie
          window.alert("Logged in as: " + username); // Display the logged-in username in an alert
          window.location.href = "index.html";
        } else {
          console.log(obj.error);
        }
      },
      
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        window.alert("AJAX request failed: " + error); // Handle AJAX request errors
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

This is `select_user.php` which is to search the a database and checks whether the user exists. If they do, then it is supposed to return the username back to Javascript, which will then set the username as part of the cookie.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $psw = $_POST['psw'];

    // Database details
    // Localhost address
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "Gardening_System";

    // Creating a connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // echo ("checkpoint 1");

    // Ensuring connection is made
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Sanitize user inputs to prevent SQL injection
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $uname);
    $psw = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $psw);

    // Checking if the username and password combination exists in the database
    $checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM Username_Password WHERE username= '$uname' AND password= '$psw'";
    // mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $uname, $psw);
    // mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $checkResult = mysqli_query($con, $checkQuery);
    // echo ("checkpoint 2");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($checkResult) > 0) {
        $userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkResult);
        $response = array('success' => true, 'result' => $userData["username"]);
        echo json_encode($response);
        // echo ("checkpoint 3");
        if (setcookie($uname)){
            header("Location: http://localhost/Gardening-System/index.html");
        }
    } else {
        // Return an error message in JSON format
        $response = array('error' => 'User does not exist');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    // If the request method is not POST, return an error message
    $response = array('error' => 'Invalid request method');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

After trying to login, it goes to the main screen, but it doesn't save the cookie and display it.

Comment: You don't need to escape strings (using `mysqli_real_escape_string`) when using prepared statements.

Comment: This is very insecure if you want to use this as an authentication mechanism. Any user can just inject a random username in the cookie and try to continue on your webpage.  Based on your example, I assume you are a novice, so the more secure approach would be to set a php server session with the username, so the backend stores the authentication instead. You will then get a php session_id in a cookie. That id will be used for php to know which session to use. In that session the username is stored (maybe even an expiration date). That way you know the user is authenticated.

Comment: Also the way you are using cookies, you do not NEED a cookie. Just use localStorage

Comment: I would not do this. Use session. Also, hash your users passwords, dont store plain text.

Comment: Unrelated to question/issue but PHPMyAdmin is not a DB system. It is a UI generally for MySQL interactions.